# Finding $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(a x)-\tan ^{-1}(b x)}{x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> Prove that
> $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(a x)-\tan ^{-1}(b x)}{x} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right);\;0<a<b$$

I do not have a clue on how to solve this. In class I have only been taught how to find converging diverging and I do not know how I could apply it here. I can understand how the numerator could give $\frac {\pi}{2}$ but then there are two arc tans so I do not how how I would solve it. And I do not understand why it is $log(a/b)$. And as usual the solution provided by the professor is inadequate as all it tells is to find the limit of arc tan tending to 0 once and tending infinity once and the next step he did says hence proved. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral $$ $$ It's a very general class of integrals with a similar value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}ax- \tan^{-1}
bx}x dx \\= &\int_0^\infty \int_b^a \frac1{1+x^2t^2}dtdx 
=\frac\pi2 \int_b^a\frac 1tdt = \frac\pi2 \ln \frac ab
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Defne $$F(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)-\tan^{-1}(bx)}{x}\right)dx$$
use the formula:
$$g(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(\alpha,t)dt \Longrightarrow g^{\prime}(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\alpha}(\alpha,t)dt$$
then show that:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=\frac{\pi}{2a}$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=-\frac{\pi}{2b}$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{1+(ax)^{2}}.x}{x}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+(ax)^{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{d(ax)}{1+(ax)^{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan(a\cdot \infty)=\frac{\pi}{2a}.$$ because $a>0.$

Finally,
$$F(a,b)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(a)+M(b)$$
and
$$-\frac{\pi}{2b}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=M^{\prime}(b).$$
$$M(b)=-\int{\frac{\pi}{2b}}db=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(b).$$

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.01249.pdf